# How to automatically determine type for user input?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to make a simple math function that takes user input, yet allows the user to not input an integer/float. I quickly learned Python does not identify type by default. Quick Google search shows using `literal_eval`, but it returns with `ValueError: malformed string` if a string is the input. This is what I have so far:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def distance_from_zero(x):
  if type(x) == int or type(x) == float:
    return abs(x)
  else:
    return "Not possible"

x = literal_eval(raw_input("Please try to enter a number "))

print distance_from_zero(x)
```

Comment: [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Comment: Note: `raw_input` is *Python2* specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like you mentioned you will get malformed string error (`ValueError`) if you get input like `ast.literal_eval('c1')`.  You will also get `SyntaxError` if you do something like `ast.literal_eval('1c')`.  You will want get the input data and then pass it to `literal_eval`.  You can then catch both of these exceptions, and then return your `'Not Possible'`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def distance_from_zero(x):
    try:
        return abs(literal_eval(x))
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        return 'Not possible'

    x = raw_input("Please try to enter a number ")

    print distance_from_zero(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I guess I needed to learn much more because I didn't even know `try` and `except` existed. Definitely didn't think of using errors as conditions!

Answer (score 0):

Just answer your query why `ValueError: malformed string` occurred if you read the literal_eval doc :

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.

so string should be inclosed by "" as used to write in editor like `s = "string"`
raw_input takes the input and convert to string data type so i have tried this and able to convert using `literal_eval`

```
>>> x=raw_input()
string
>>> x= "\""+x+"\"" # concatenating the "" to string
>>> literal_eval(x)
'string'
>>>
```